# How to get SignalR IHubContext from DI in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, signalr-hub

I have many Hubs and register them:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<FinanceHub>("/hub/finance");
    endpoints.MapHub<PartnersHub>("/hub/partners");
    ...
    endpoints.MapHub<WarehousesHub>("/hub/warehouses");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

I register SignalR:

```
services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = signalrMaxMessageLimit * 8192;
}).AddMessagePackProtocol(conf =>
{
    conf.FormatterResolvers.Clear();
    conf.FormatterResolvers.Add(CircularResolver.Instance);
});
```

They work as SignalR hubs. But when I try to resolve them in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase:

```
private IHubContext<FinanceHub> financeHub => provider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<FinanceHub>>();

public PaymentRegisterController(
    ILogger<ServiceController> logger,
    IServiceProvider _provider) : base(logger)
{
    provider = _provider;
}
```

I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext`1[Engy.Plantain.Procurement.Backend.Hubs.FinanceHub]'
> has been registered.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You registered the enpoints. But did you register the Services? `services.AddSignalR();` ?

Comment: @Fildor No. Services register automatically by registering endpoints, don't they?

Comment: Last time I checked, you need to at least do `services.AddSignalR();`.

Comment: @Fildor oh, sure. I register SignalR. I added into the post message.

Comment: Does it work, if you do CTOR injection?

Comment: @Fildor no, if I try to resolve in CTOR (public PaymentRegisterController(IHubContext<FinanceHub> _financeHub)), I get the same exception.

Comment: But the hubs work and the website (the frontend) communicate with them successfully.

Answer (score 1):

As eveyone, I am sure, thought, it was my mistake. In the API-controller I was trying to resolve **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext** instead of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext**.
Now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new way to do it in `.NET 6`

You can have multiple Resolvers

```
services.AddSignalR()
.AddMessagePackProtocol(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard
   .WithResolver(MessagePack.Resolvers.StandardResolver.Instance)
.WithResolver(MessagePack.Resolvers.NativeDateTimeResolver.Instance)
    .WithSecurity(MessagePackSecurity.UntrustedData);
});
```